# Iterating over an array recursively causes invalid results in callback function

Tags: php, recursion, switch-statement, comparison

I'm trying to iterate over every element of an array recursively to get the values where the key is equal to `page_id` or `content_id`.

The problem is that in callback function, in a switch statement I get completely weird behaviour, where case is matched but value is different.

This was driving me nuts for quite some time. I even tried to use strict comparison like `if($key === 'component_id') print $key; die();`. I'm expecting to get 'component_id' as the output but get '0'. How is that possible?

While writing this question, I also noticed this happens when there is indexed array at some point, but I'm not sure if that is the problem.

Here is an example code from full solution.

Thanks.

```
<?php

class Arr
{
    public static function map($array, $callback, $recursive = false)
    {
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            $array[$key] = $callback($key, $value);
            if($recursive && is_array($array[$key])) {
                $array[$key] = static::map($array[$key], $callback, true);
            }
        }
        return $array;
    }
}

$data = [
    'id' => 12,
    'data' => [
        'terms' => [
            [
                'href' => null,
                'icon' => 'lock',
                'target' => '_blank'
            ],
            [
                'href' => 'http://example.com',
                'icon' => 'lock',
                'target' => '_blank'
            ]
        ],
        'license_info' => [
            'content_id' => 6
        ]
    ]
];

$contents = [];
$pages = [];

Arr::map($data, function ($key, $value) use (&$contents, &$pages) {
    switch ($key) {
        case 'content_id':
            print $key; die(); // 0  ?????
            $contents[] = $value;
            break;
        case 'page_id':
            $pages[] = $value;
            break;
    }

    return $value;
}, true);
```

I expected the output to be `component_id`, but I got `0`.

Also I know I could use `array_walk` or `array_walk_recursive`, but I prefer this approach as it's more elegant and readable in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks ok. The problem is that `0 == 'content_id'` is **True**. And `switch` in PHP is using loose (`==`) comparison. And because in `terms` you have two values without string keys, they are automatically indexed starting at 0.
So what you get is not when your function finds

```
'content_id' => 6
```

but when it finds

```
/* 0 => */
[
   'href' => null,
   'icon' => 'lock',
   'target' => '_blank'
],
```

EDIT:
Bottom line is - you have to use `if` with strict comparison `===` in this case (or use string keys everywhere).

Comment: @rms Thank you ;), I could not imagine if `0 == 'content_id'` was **True**. Plus when using strict comparison I left the switch statement intact, so that's why I thought something was wrong.

Comment: @GiorgiBotsvadze I know, it's crazy :) To make it even better `1 == 'content_id'` is **False** :DD